# Split valeus on arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, split

Some values on my python array looks like this: [..., '127,39 0,24868']
I tryed to split but it doesent work

```
        y = 41
        while y>=0:
            print(" ")
            x = 15
            while x>0:
                try:
                    
                    values[y][x].split(' ')
                    print(values[y][x])
                except:
                    print()
                x -= 1
            y -= 1
```

Comment: please kindly clarify what you are trying to do and show the required output you want

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do with this code but if you split string then you have to assign result to variable i.e `result = values[y][x].split(' ')`

Comment: code would be simpler and more readable if you would use `for`-loops with `range()` instead of `while`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the return value of the `split`-Method:

```
for row in reversed(values):
    for cell in reversed(row):
        print(cell.split())
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the reversed but not in the firt position?
like this:

for row in reversed(values - 1):

Comment: If copying the list is acceptable, you could use a slice: `for row in values[-1:0:-1]:`...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
b = [y  for x in a if x!= ... for y in x.split(',')]
```